# Replace tilde with pattern substitution

Tags: bash, shell, rhel-7

Normally I use the `${parameter/pattern/string}` construct
in bash to replace characters.

For example, `${i//(/_}` replaces all `(` characters with `_` in `$i`. 
For illustration:

```
find . -depth -type d -name '*(*' -execdir bash -c 'for i; do mv "$i" "${i//(/_}"; done' _ {} +
```

I cannot get it to work with `~`. 
`${i//~/_}` yields the value of `$i`, unchanged,
even if it contains tilde(s).

It's weird – it works with every single other symbol I use except a question mark. Any ideas with the tilde?

Comment: Why don't you escape the tilde with a backslash?

Answer (score 3):

[bash(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) doesn’t clearly document the fact that,
when you do

```
${parameter/pattern/string}
```

the *`pattern`* and *`string`* are subject to all the expansions
that apply to plain (unquoted) words on the command line. 
Consider this example:

```
$ balance=credit

$ fire=red

$ sky=blue

$ echo "${balance/$fire/$sky}"
cblueit
```

Your problem, of course, is that `~` gets expanded to your home directory:

```
$ i=foo/home/JandPbar

$ echo "${i/~/_}"
foo_bar
```

So, as suggested in the comment, you need to quote/escape the `~`,
with `"${i/'~'/_}"` or `"${i/\~/_}"`.